# ArrayList references behavior

Tags: java, reference, arraylist

I am totally confused with ArrayList behavior. Wrote really long post, then realized no one is going to analyse huge code, so just core of the problem. Numbers are for convenience, but in my app these 0 and 24 are dynamic values.

```
ArrayList<VoipBlock> sortedBlocks = new ArrayList<VoipBlock>();

VoipBlock vb3 =new VoipBlock();

vb3=sortedBlocks.get(0);

vb3.setPacketNumber(24);
```

Essentially my final aim is to: modify and add back to arrayList as new value. However when I do that the guy at position 0 in ArrayList -> **unsortedBlocks.get(0);** replicates all the changes done to **vb3** which of course is not what I want. I want vb3 acquire same values as VoipBlock inside of ArrayList, but I want it to be detached.

This is yet another case of passing by reference. I hate technical explanations - Java passes everything by value, BUT in some cases it passes references by values - this is same as saying not-oily oil. Please help.

It reminds me my start of learning JavaScript - I hated the language - until I watched proper materials at lynda.com - JavaScript Good Practices? - Diagrams killed me. It is the lazy description that turns us-youth away from brilliant technology, not the technology itself.

Please don't let it bother my stress and don't be in any way offended by me, it is just general complaining, maybe someone will look at it and make life better :-)

Thanks for Your time,
Desperately awaiting for help :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve your objective you can use clone method. you have to override this method in VoipBlock class

Lets say VoipBlock is as follows

```
public class VoipBlock {

     private int packetNumber;
     private String type;

     public int getPacketNumber() {
      return packetNumber;
     }

     public String getType() {
      return type;
     }

     public void setPacketNumber(int value) {
       packetNumber = value;
     } 

     public void setType(String value) {
       type = value
     }

     public VoipBlock clone() {
        VoipBlock clone = VoipBlock();
        clone.setType(this.getType());
        clone.setPacketNumber(this.getPacketNumber());
        return clone;
     }

}
```

So, using the same code you can do like as follows

```
ArrayList<VoipBlock> sortedBlocks = new ArrayList<VoipBlock>();

VoipBlock vb3 =new VoipBlock();

sortedBlocks.add(vb3);

vb3=sortedBlocks.get(0).clone();

vb3.setPacketNumber(24);
```

Note that upon calling clone method in above code segment, vb3 get assigned with a new VoipBlock instance. And already inserted VoipBlock to the array remains unchanged.

if you are looking to have kind of sample instances of VoipBlock instances which you later wanted to use in creating similar instances like them. check on immutability/mutability aspect of the code. check "Effective Java" by Joshua Blouch

Comment: Thank You, as always only thanks to this website I am still doing what I am doing :-)

Comment: One of the things mentioned in Effective Java is that `clone()` should be used rarely and with caution.  Using a copy constructor or factory method is probably preferable.

Answer (score 1):

The following will always copy the reference of b to a:

```
AnyClass a = ...;
AnyClass b = ...;
a = b;
```

What you want is probably to clone the object:

```
a = b.clone();
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you're a bit unsure about how references and values work. I think the rule of thumb is that primitive types like `int, char, boolean` and maybe `String` are copied but Objects just have their reference passed.

The line `vb3=sortedBlocks.get(0);` completely replaces whatever vb3 used to be with the first thing in the ArrayList. And yes, it won't be a copy, it will be a reference to the same object in memory. So whatever you do will affect both of them. You need to either manually copy over all the information you need or to use a `clone()` or `copy()` function.

So for example, in your code, the line `VoipBlock vb3 =new VoipBlock();` is a bit redundant because you're overwriting the new instance straight away.

Comment: Thank You! I do that new operator always I had issues without it before in while loop when you don't use new it keeps previous reference. So I now I do properly :-)

Answer (score 0):

What you really need here is to either use a copy constructor or declare VoipBlock to be Clonable so you can use the clone() method.

What you are interpreting as passing by reference is not actually passing by reference.  Java objects are really pointers.  Because of this you are passing the value of the pointer.  So when you do:

```
vb3=sortedBlocks.get(0);
```

you are really assigning vb3 to point to the same locations in memory as sortedBlocks.get(0).  Therefore when you manipulate vb3 properties through their setters, the result is seen in both.

If you want two separate pointers you need to use the **new** keyword or use the clone() method which does this under the hood.

An example to prove this is:

```
public class Person {
  private String name;

  public Person(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  public String getName() {
    return this.name;
  }

  public void setName(String name) {
     this.name = name;
  }
}

public class Main {

  public void doSomething(Person p) {
    p = new Person("Bob");
    System.out.println(p.getName());
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Person p = new Person("Billy");
    System.out.println(p.getName());
    doSomething(p);
    System.out.println(p.getName());
  }
}
```

Since Java is pass by value the output will be: Billy, Bob, Billy.  If Java were pass by reference it would be Billy, Bob, Bob.  If I did not do the new Person in the doSomething() method and instead used the setName() method I would end up with Billy, Bob, Bob also but this is due to the fact I'm now modifying off the same pointer not that I passed by reference as the example above proves that's not the case.